# How to duplicate a record via PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to duplicate a record via PDO. 
Can you help me?

Comment: use `insert ... select... `

Answer (score 1):

Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

For example;

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`name`)
   (SELECT `name`
   FROM `foo` 
   WHERE `id` = 1)
```

In short, you'd need to specify the field names (don't add in the primary keys to the field list on the `INSERT` or `SELECT`).

#### Illustrated example

```
CREATE TABLE `dupe` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `dupe` (id, name) VALUES(1, 'bar');
```

So, now we have a table with a primary key, so we cannot "easily" duplicate rows.

```
INSERT INTO `dupe`
SELECT * FROM `dupe` WHERE `name` = 'bar'

[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Ah, ok. Let's specify the fields we want to duplicate values of.

We want to duplicate the first row, we would run;

```
INSERT INTO `dupe` (`name`)
SELECT `name` FROM `dupe` WHERE `name` = 'bar';
```

Now we've duplicated the row, but not the primary key.

```
mysql> select * from dupe;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | bar  |
|  2 | bar  |
+----+------+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: thanks, but this error returned : #1062 - Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: thanks, but I don't have field names (operation should automatically).